# List of tuples: remove tuples by comparison of element if they have another identical element

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension

I have a list of tuples looking like
`items = [(id, date), ...]`

I want to filter the list of tuples so I'm only holding on to one tuple for every unique id, and for all occurrences of tuples which have the same ID, I want to keep the entry with the most recent date value.

For example:

```
items = [('1', '12/2/2016'), ('2', '12/20/2016'), ('1', '12/24/2016')]

# Apply filter comparing tuples with identical [0] element based off [1] element

items = [('2', '12/20/2016'), ('1', '12/24/2016')]
```

I'm looking for the most elegant and 'pythonic' solution to this problem, thanks!

Comment: sort them, then use `itertools.groupby` to group them by id, then use `max` with a key function to find the most recent date.  I think you can use `datetime.date` for that, but I'd have to check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're going to sort them, then group them using `itertools.groupby` then use `max` to find the most recent date.  We'll write a key function that takes one of these tuples and returns a `datetime.date` object.

```
from datetime import date
from itertools import groupby

def make_date(t):
    month, day, year = map(int, t[1].split('/'))
    return date(year, month, day)

items = [max(g, key=make_date) for k, g in groupby(sorted(items, key=lambda x: int(x[0])), key=lambda x: x[0])]
```

EDIT:  We'll just get `t[-1]` to get the last element of the tuple and use `datetime.datetime.strptime` to get the datetime

```
from datetime import datetime
from itertools import groupby

items = [max(g, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[-1], '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')) for k, g in groupby(sorted(items, key=lambda x: int(x[0])), key=lambda x: x[0])]
```

Comment: How would I approach this with a larger tuple (size 5), I tried to omit unnecessary details in my original post however my actual data looks something like: 
'('104587520', '13347465', '17776122', 'Update', '12/29/2016 13:32:45')'
Where tuple[0] is the ID I'm filtering on and tuple[5] is the date I'm comparing

Answer (score 3):

One approach is simply to convert to a dictionary and back again (if you really need it as a list of tuples - or leave it as a dict).
If the tuples are not in date order then you can simply `sorted` based on date:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> items = [('1', '12/2/2016'), ('2', '12/20/2016'), ('1', '12/24/2016')]
>>> d = dict(sorted(items, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[1], '%m/%d/%Y')))
>>> items = list(d.items())
[('2', '12/20/2016'), ('1', '12/24/2016')]
```

Comment: So this relies on `dict()` ignoring all but the first tuple with the same first element (the key)? I was not aware of this behavior.

Comment: `dict` keys are unique, so any future `key` overwrites the previous `value`, `sorted` ensures that the last `key` has the latest `date`